# Combine elements of list

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a problem with Python and hope someone can help me. I have a list, for example this one:

```
list = [['a','b','c'],['a','c1','d1'],['b','c1','c2']]
```

I want to combine the list in a way that all arrays with the same index[0] will be together, so then it will be like:

```
a, b, c, c1, d1
b, c1, c2
```

I tried something like this, but I did not get it working..

```
list = [['a','b','c'],['a','c1','d1'],['b','c1','c2']]
empty_list = []
for i in list:
    if i not in empty_list:
       empty_list.append(i)
    print empty_list
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this :)

```
old_list = [['a','b','c'],['a','c1','d1'],['b','c1','c2']]
prev = None
empty_list = []
for l in old_list: # iterate through each sub list, sub list as l
    if l[0] == prev:
        # append your elements to existing sub list
        for i in l: # iterate through each element in sub list
            if i not in empty_list[-1]:
                empty_list[-1].append(i) 
    else:
        empty_list.append(l) # create new sub list
        prev = l[0] # update prev

print(empty_list)
# [['a', 'b', 'c', 'c1', 'd1'], ['b', 'c1', 'c2']]
```

Comment: Thanks, I am also wondering how to get the ; between the sets, so it will be '[['a', 'b', 'c'; 'c1', 'd1'], ['b', 'c1', 'c2']]. Do you know how to fix that?

Comment: u mean just a delimeter/separator to indicate the start of the list?

Comment: can just add `empty_list[-1].append(';') ` right after `if l[0] == prev:`. Your print output would be `[['a', 'b', 'c', ';', 'c1', 'd1'], ['b', 'c1', 'c2']]`
`

Answer (score 1):

Using [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

listt = [['a','b','c'],['a','c1','d1'],['b','c1','c2']]

grouped = [list(g) for _,g in groupby(listt,itemgetter(0))]
result = [[item for sslist in slist for item in sslist] for slist in grouped]
```

Answer (score 0):

An `OrderedDict` can do most of the work:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

l = [['a','b','c'], ['a','c1','d1'], ['b','c1','c2']]

d = OrderedDict()
for el in l:
  d.setdefault(el[0], el[0:1]).extend(el[1:])

print(d.values())
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also try using defaultdict(list)

```
l = [['a','b','c'], ['a','c1','d1'], ['b','c1','c2']]
from collections import defaultdict
d_dict = defaultdict(list)
for i in l:
    d_dict[i[0]].extend(i[1:])

[ list(k) + v  for k, v in d_dict.items() ]
```

Output:

```
[['a', 'b', 'c', 'c1', 'd1'], ['b', 'c1', 'c2']]
```